# Execute form environmental variable while stack is not executable

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, shellcode

Strange thing happened. I created EGG=NOPs + shellcode. Then i get the address of EGG;
[image]

I made buffer overflow and jumped to it and get the shell(address of shell is the second parametr). How is this possible if the stack is not executable?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's surely because you are not executing anything in the stack. Without the binary in question, I will try to guess what is happening here.

With the first `print "A"*268 + '\x68\x96\x04\x08'` you are probably overwriting a pointer to point to `0x08049668`. This address is probably a [GOT entry](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/what-is-plt-got/1993#1993) for a function called later like `printf()` or `exit()`.

Then, in the second argument you specify the value that the pointer is pointing to. In other words, you overwrite that GOT entry (`0x08049668`) with your shell code address (`0xbffff891`).

So, when the program calls that shared library function (`exit()`, `printf()`, `whatever()`, ...), your shell code will be called instead, because it has been overwritten.

In this process, no code is put in the stack. A pointer in the stack is overwritten. That's all. Then you use that overwritten pointer to overwrite a shared library function address with the shell code address.